# Jedis in scala and handling errors

Tags: scala

I am trying to find the best way to handle jedis commands from scala. I am trying to implement a finally block, and prevent the java exceptions from bubbling up to my caller.

Does the following code make sense, and is it the best I can do performance wise, if I want to ensure that I handle exceptions when redis may be down temporarily? This trait would be extended by an object, and I'd call objectname.del(key). I feel like I'm combining too many concepts (Either, Option, Try, feels like there should be a cleaner way)

```
trait MyExperiment {
  implicit class TryOps[T](val t: Try[T])  {
    def eventually[Ignore](effect: => Ignore): Try[T] = {
      val ignoring = (_: Any) => { effect; t }
      t transform (ignoring, ignoring)
    }
  }


  val jpool:JedisPool = initialize()

  // init the pool at object creation
  private def initialize(): JedisPool =
  {
    val poolConfig   = new JedisPoolConfig()
    poolConfig.setMaxIdle(10)
    poolConfig.setMinIdle(2)
    poolConfig.setTestWhileIdle(true)
    poolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true)
    poolConfig.setTestOnReturn(true)
    poolConfig.setNumTestsPerEvictionRun(10)
    new JedisPool(  poolConfig , "localhost" )
  }

  // get a resource from pool. This can throw an error if redis is    
  // down
  def  getFromPool: Either[Throwable,Jedis] =
    Try(jpool.getResource) match {
      case Failure(m) => Left(m)
      case Success(m) => Right(m)
    }

  // return an object to pool
  // i believe this may also throw an error if redis is down?
  def  returnToPool(cache:Jedis): Unit =
    Try(jpool.returnResource(cache))

  // execute a command -- "del" in this case, (wrapped by 
  // the two methods above)
  def del(key: String) : Option[Long] =  {
    getFromPool match {
      case Left(m) => None
      case Right(m) => Try(m.del(key)) eventually returnToPool(m) match {
        case Success(r) => Option(r)
        case Failure(r) => None
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis-nb or https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis, doing things Scala way :)

Comment: Because at least I know jredis is a well tried-and-true component whereas I can find no war stories of anyone using scala-redis in production, and how performant it is (I did find this, which doesn't make scala-redis shine: https://gist.github.com/felipehummel/3909583) . And because I don't want to learn and pick an off the shelf product whenever I run into a small roadlock.

Comment: eh., that should be "I want to learn and not pick an off the shelf...". Pox on whoever decided you can only edit a comment for five minutes.

Comment: I have a war story from using scala-redis in production. It does not implement pipeline() correctly. https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis/issues/131

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer, but I moved on after doing some performance testing. Using the standard java-ish exception blocks ended up being much faster at high iterations (at 10,000 iterations, it was about 2.5x faster than the (bad) code above). That also cleaned up my code, although it's more verbose.

So the answer I arrived at is to use the Java-style exception blocks which provide for the *finally* construct. I believe it should be significantly faster, as long as exceptions are a very rare occurance.